# How do I implement this circuit with transistors?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics

What is a schematic of this logic diagram? I've already implemented the SR latch and this is just a simpler version that only 'sets'.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that your logic diagram is a latch?  When A goes high, the output will be latched high with no means to reset the output back to low.  Also, mark the schematic with A, B, and OUT nodes.  Also, 1 V is not enough to turn on any LED.  Read the datasheet for your LED.

Comment: The circuit as drawn is just two B-E diodes in parallel, trying to drive an LED (with no current limiting resistor) from a 1V supply.

Comment: The datasheet for the LTL-307EE red LED has a typical forward voltage of 2V at 20mA like most red LEDs. The LED draws almost no current and produces almost no light when it gets only 1.6V. The transistors have a voltage drop of 0.6V at a low current. Then the circuit needs at least 1.6V + 0.6V= 2.2V to produce very dim light, 2.7V to produce very bright light and with about 3V, the LED and/or transistors burn out. The LED has a range of forward voltage. At 20mA some are 1.8V, most are near 2.0V and some are 2.6V.

Comment: I'm aware of the inaccurate voltage, current, etc measurements I did this circuit on my breadboard. I was just trying to show a very simple schematic. since I did it in a rush, I probably forgot to add other things as well (that's my fault, and should have given more time to it). Yes, I'm aware that this was a latch. Thanks for responding

Comment: Since you know the shortcomings of your diagram, please edit the drawing and your question to make it more clear. As it is if you ask "what's wrong with this circuit?" we have to start by telling you a bunch of things you now say you already know.

Comment: I see ill take consideration next time.

Comment: This circuit clearly seem to rely on the assumption that on power-up, the output of the OR gate will somehow be 0. There is *no* reason for it to be 0 rather than 1. In fact, it may depend on the type of gate used, how the supply ramps up, and various external factors. The initial output value is undefined as long as A is low. So it's kinda hard to replicate the behavior of a circuit that has undefined behavior.

Comment: A K-map of your "starting" circuit should help.

Comment: this circuit may power up in the high state, so just connecting the output pin to logic high is a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Latching 'or' gate.]

Assume the input and output start off 'low'. Now if the input goes 'high', the output will latch 'high' (because of the feedback) and it will remain 'high' irrespective of what the input does from that point on.

Comment: Note regarding startup behavior: Assume Q1 and Q2 are off, and then power is applied. Until Q2 turns on R4 is essentially shorted to 5V. Since Q1 and Q2 are mostly identical, the B-E capacitance and ratio of R4 to R1 ensure that Q2 will turn on *before* Q1 does. If R1 and R4's values were interchanged, this circuit could perhaps be prone to powering up in the latched state. As shown, it should work well, perhaps with a noise filtering capacitor added between Q1's B and E.

Answer (score 3):

What kinds of transistors are you planning to use?

Logic gates can be created with for example transistor-transistor logic or by CMOS logic.

An OR gate by using CMOS logic is explained here: http://www.vlsifacts.com/and-and-or-gate-using-cmos-technology/

An OR gate by using TTL logic with BJTs is explained here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/ttl-nor-and-or-gates/

However, by connecting the output to one of its inputs, if the output has ever been a logical "1", all you get is a logical 1. It will never switch to logical 0.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, an SCR-like structure could be used, as shown below. The SCR is a latching device: once it turns ON, the power has to be removed to turn it OFF.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTR1yB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For rail-to-rail output, the SCR can be supplemented with a push-pull output stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDgFk5.png)</sup>

The SCR acts like a switch between points A and B: once the input goes high, the SCR latches ON and connects point A to B through a one-diode voltage drop. I.e. think of the SCR "ON" (with input removed) as a diode between A and B.

Latching behavior can also be obtained with a "ring" of two inverters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWYgr3.png)</sup>

Above, R1 and C1 ensure startup with the output LOW. D1 and NOT3 act like an open-collector/open-drain stage.

That translates almost directly to CMOS. The five transistors can be discrete, or come from a *just one* 4007 transistor array chip (CD4007, MC14007, HEF4007, etc.).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEF0ge.png)</sup>

For fastest possible latching action, the input should be complementary, and both inverter inputs should be driven:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffrEQz.png)</sup>

M11-M14 are an inverting buffer with propagation delay similar to the non-inverting buffer M7-M10. M15 ensures startup in the LOW output state. M5 and M6 flip the state of inverters M3-M4 and M1-M2 respectively. In a practical implementation, M1-M6 can be a CD4007, and M7-M14 can be CD4041.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I posted an implementation of that circuit in [this answer last month](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/643317/65892). My implementation is pretty much just an ordinary RTL OR gate.

[Here's the circuit in Falstad's simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKABdxiUQUUAWHgkI9+UcFGgJifPNMLY+ZaXkLCYqyBjxgMpEsQQpieZFQAmdAGYBDAK4AbNuxC4BvAdkIn3YiA2zQhDjY2Lp8vJiEYHjkMJCECHgxYIR8GGiQfNjcYHAgFjYOTgBOnNw+YFwumWK8cCwA5mXVApXc2VSdLKVtIq1g5aJUdZAsAO7NFVU6at3NM+AD4BhqIvVNKEI8fMNbm6ujTZ7eOy5eggdz+zz4FyB4nSBpowBK4CgmKfdUX4+nSI8YAg5scbiZQQ9amhxndIRCuhNXGC7mgTKNETVUS0+lAYaCsXwvlj0U8ibdCcIfKMAM7vT6U0S-MQ2ezUugsFLcGTDURCHlufJWOyOBj2OhmcSA2CsJp8nFy-iAuYUnHcnFUZ4sWnMHIrRbcSE-EAstkwioMgSGs1bSE+K0TO0-Jb20kW11nNEwlWgnUe3ETX0+pZUlhAA), and below is a screenshot:

[image: A resistor–transistor logic circuit that implements an OR gate with one of its inputs connected to its output]

My circuit is more or less the same as the circuit in [James's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/646875/65892), but mine has a pull-down resistor in order to ensure that the latch is off when it's powered up.

Answer (score 1):

As implementation should be "BJT", you should be aware of "analog" behavior.

[image]